# how to refresh counter value of one controller from another angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have a cart counter which is in header controller. and a add to cart button which is in image view controller. I want to set cart counter from the image view controller. SO every time add to cart is clicked it changes the cart value.

Header controller :

```
 decorpotCtrls.controller('DecorpotCtrl', [ '$scope', '$routeParams', 'cart',
    function($scope, $routeParams, cart) {
        $scope.cartCounter = cart.getCartCounter();
    } ]);
```

Image Controller : -

```
  decorpotCtrls.controller('ImageViewController', [
    '$scope',
    '$routeParams',
    'imageView',
    '$auth',
    'cart',
    function($scope, $routeParams, imageView, $auth, cart) {

    $scope.addToCart = function(groupid) {
            console.log($auth.isAuthenticated());
            return cart.addToCart(groupid);

        };

    } ]);
```

cart Html : -

```
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cart({{cartCounter}})
```

add to cart from image controller -

```
 <div id="addToCart" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg buyNCartButton" ng-click="addToCart(groupid)">Add To Cart</div>
```

cart service -

```
services.service('cart', function($http){
    var counter =0 ;
    sessionStorage.setItem('cartCounter', counter);
    //var 
    return {
        checkout : function(){

        },

        addToCart : function(gruopid){

            counter++;
            return counter;
        },

        getCartCounter : function(){
            return counter;
        }

    };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do one thing set method reference to `$scope.cartCounter` like

```
$scope.cartCounter = cart.getCartCounter;
```

Then on HTML you could call that method like `cartCounter()` that will get evaluated on each digest.

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
Cart({{cartCounter()}})
```

Comment: but if i say addToCart(), will this refresh the count ??

Comment: @user2696466 yes, it will. Why don't you try?

Comment: Awesome... Its working. still learning magics of $scope. Thanks Pankaj

Comment: @user2696466 Glad to here that..Thanks :)

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your help bro from commenting..Appreciated it. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use $rootScope in controller. All $scopes are "childs" of $rootScope.

```
decorpotCtrls.controller('ImageViewController', [
'$rootScope',
'$scope',
'$routeParams',
'imageView',
'$auth',
'cart',
function($scope,$rootScope, $routeParams, imageView, $auth, cart) {

$scope.addToCart = function(groupid) {
        $rootScope.counter++;
        console.log($auth.isAuthenticated());
        return cart.addToCart(groupid);

    };

} ]);
```